# Change all Components with className="theme" from green to blue on an event in React

Tags: reactjs

In App.css, I have

```
.theme {
  color: green;
}
```

And I have className="theme" scattered in multiple components.

Is there a way to change the theme color from green to blue on an event?

If not, how should I design my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You can create 2 classes named `.blue-theme` and `.green-theme`

Whenever, some event occurs,

```
onClick = (themeCol) => {
 this.setState({theme:thmeCol})
}

render(){
 return(
  <button onClick={()=>onClick('blue-theme')}>Blue theme</button>
  <button onClick={()=>onClick('green-theme')}>Green theme</button>
 <div className={this.state.theme}> Sample </div>
 )
}
```

You can pass the value of theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
const themeClass = "";

  if (event-as-wanted){
     themeClass="theme";
    }

  className={themeClass}
```

also you can use style insted of className in same file

```
const theme ={
color: '';
};

style={theme}
```

and change it with events like

```
 if (event-as-wanted){
         theme.color = "green";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render the `<style/>` tag to override style definition for the class in the whole document.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    red: true,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="foo">Foo</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ red: !this.state.red })}>
          Toggle Red
        </button>
        {this.state.red && <style>{".foo { color: red }"}</style>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that inside JSX tags, curly brackets will be picked up by the interpreter and may break the parser. To avoid that, you should put your CSS inside a string like in the example above.

Adding a `<style/>` tag to CSS document will override any equally specific CSS rules that came before that. Once the condition is no longer met, the style tag will be removed and the original styling will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

in react.js just set the state of color to whatever and on a click event toggle the color

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {color: green};
this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
}

changeColor() {
const newcolor = this.state.color == green ? blue : green;
this.setState({ color: newcolor});
}

render() {
  return (
  <div class="theme" style={{color: this.statecolor}}>
  <button onClick={this.changeColor}>
  </button>
//put all html withing the parent DOM of element with class theme accordingly or it wont render.
</div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make two class, `.green-theme{
color:'green'}` and similarly, blue theme.
Mantain a `REDUX STATE`, CURRENT_THEME. Upon event fire, change the redux state accordingly and everywhere, where you want to use CURRENT_THEME, use it using `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather try to use almost pure CSS solution:

in App.css

```
#App.first-theme .theme { color:green; }
#App.second-theme .theme { color:blue; }
```

in App's render:

```
<div id="App" className={this.state.currentTheme}>
  <AnotherComponent1 />
  <AnotherComponent2 />
</div>
```

All you need to do is to change `this.state.currentTheme` appropriately. You can even use prop injected from the redux.

Almost all other solutions posted here have the same flaw: you have to adapt all your components to use the theme. Using this solution, you are able to change app's appearance without additional code in your components.

Trust me, injecting the same property from redux store/react context for every component will give you headaches and a lot of unnecessary code.

You should also try to avoid generating additional `<style>` tags - you will end up having plenty of `!important` and HTML, logic, and CSS in one file. What a mess! Imagine, what would happen if you would like to use SCSS in the future...